# Update Query With Group By

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I know you can not use aggregates in an Update Query - but I can not fathom how to write the syntax for this update.  This is sample data

```
UserID   Item            InStock     R2S
14         S0            Yes
28         M23           No
10         Ca2           No
14         G01           No
16         G21           Yes
16         G33           Yes
```

Now what I am after is for each UserID if InStock is yes for all items than update R2S to yes

I tried the below syntax, however that does not take into account the userID that have multiples like 14 and 16 etc, it just looks line by line.

How can I alter this to ONLY update userID 16 to Yes since BOTH items are r2s?

```
UPDATE send SET R2S = 'Yes' WHERE (((InStock)='Yes'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is SQL Server, but it should work or be close.

```
update send
set R2S = 'Yes'
from send
join (select UserId
      from send
      group by UserId
      having min(InStock) = 'Yes') Maxes
on send.UserId = Maxes.UserId
```

The subquery eliminates anyone that has a 'No' and then we join on that.

I don't like that a data point lives in 2 places (the fact that there are no "No"s).  The query should be done when you are ready to use it.

Another way that might be easier for the next reader to follow:

```
    update send
    set R2S = 'Yes'
    from send
    where UserId not in (select UserId
          from send
          where InStock = 'No')
```